# Android library imported via jitpack.io results in "package does not exist" error, though previous versions can be imported fine

Tags: android, android-library, jitpack

I have an open-source Android library uploaded on GitHub (I am the author of the library). A day back, I released a new version of the library, making it compatible with Android SDK 34. After creating the release on GitHub, I could successfully build it on jitpack.io. I haven't made any significant changes in the recent commits; just removed a public implementation of an interface and changed it into a private variable. It works fine, as confirmed by the demo app that I created along with the library (also available on GitHub).

The issue starts when I try to import the library into one of my other Android projects. The old version of the library can be imported fine. However, when I change the version of the library and sync the changes, I start getting `Cannot resolve symbol ...` everywhere. If I try to rebuild, Gradle says that the package does not exist. Reverting to the old version immediately fixes all errors.

I have attempted to invalidate caches and restart Android Studio, but in vain. How do I fix this?

Link to the library: [AudioFocusController](https://github.com/WrichikBasu/AudioFocusController)
Previous release tag: `v2.1`
Latest release tag: `3.0.0` (no `v` in the latest release)
Gradle version: 8.3  (uses OpenJDK 17)

P.S.: I believe I could have messed up the module `build.gradle` file for the library while moving over to Gradle 8.3. Here is how my **new** `build.gradle` file looks:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android {
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    publishing {
        singleVariant('release') {
            withSourcesJar()
            withJavadocJar()
        }
    }

    namespace 'in.basulabs.audiofocuscontroller'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

}

project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                components.getByName('release')
                groupId = 'in.basulabs.audiofocuscontroller'
                artifactId = 'library'
                version = '3.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### The old one:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 3
        versionName "2.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}

project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId = 'in.basulabs.audiofocuscontroller'
                artifactId = 'library'
                version = '2.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```